# Can the Frost Arrow rune cause a chain reaction?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Frost Arrow rune for the [Elemental arrow](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/elemental-arrow) skill reads:

> Fire a frost arrow that splits into multiple arrows after hitting its target

What I'd like to know is: can these split arrows split themselves? Can I create a chain reaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Frost Arrow only splits the fist time. As you can read by its description: "Fire **a frost arrow** that splits into multiple arrows after hitting its **target**, dealing 160% weapon damage as Cold. Affected enemies have their movement speed slowed by 60% for 1 seconds." The initial Frost Arrow is the only one that will split.

Also you can see on [this](http://diablo3area.com/diablo3-demonhunter-skills.php) website : Frost Arrow: Turns into a frost arrow that explodes out conic damage from the back of the **first target hit** for 160% of weapon damage.